# Error [ValidationError]: Unable to fetch parameters [/route53resolver/query-log-id] from parameter store for this account

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I get the following error when trying to use a Parameter that is shared from another account.

```
 ❌  SensorsRootHub-egress-stack failed: Error [ValidationError]: Unable to fetch parameters [/route53resolver/query-log-id] from parameter store for this account.
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:46692)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:91437)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:90885)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:199281)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:192833)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:157705)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:158035
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:193125)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:199356)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:376:91605) {
  code: 'ValidationError',
  time: 2024-03-10T14:41:14.406Z,
  requestId: 'a8081114-6ede-4867-9c72-4032284d0490',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 788.1716239431858
}
```

From [CloudFormation Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types): `For SSM parameters shared by another AWS account, enter the full parameter ARN.`, however, when trying to reference the full ARN of the Parameter, I get the following error:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  @jsii/kernel.RuntimeError: Error: Parameter names must be fully qualified (if they include "/" they must also begin with a "/"): arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:402736836567:parameter/route53resolver/query-log-id
      at Kernel._Kernel_ensureSync (/tmp/tmpe5jnm3bc/lib/program.js:10491:23)
      at Kernel.sinvoke (/tmp/tmpe5jnm3bc/lib/program.js:9876:102)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (/tmp/tmpe5jnm3bc/lib/program.js:11696:36)
      at KernelHost.run (/tmp/tmpe5jnm3bc/lib/program.js:11656:22)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/tmp/tmpe5jnm3bc/lib/program.js:11657:46)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
```

The code:

```py
vpc: IVpc

query_log_id = ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(
    self, parameter_name="/route53resolver/query-log-id"
)

route53resolver.CfnResolverQueryLoggingConfigAssociation(
    self,
    id="QueryLogConfigAssociation",
    resolver_query_log_config_id=query_log_id,
    resource_id=vpc.vpc_id
)
```

I tried to resolve the parameter from the CLI and it only worked when using the full ARN value, else, I'm getting `An error occurred (ParameterNotFound) when calling the GetParameter operation`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported according to the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm):

> Currently, CloudFormation doesn't support cross-account SSM parameter access.

The documentation you linked to is referring to parameter types for CloudFormation parameters, which is not what CDK uses when generating references to SSM parameters.

Comment: This is only for **ssm dynamic reference**. 
The documentation I linked states that CloudFormation handles cross-account if the full ARN is given, I just couldn't find how to pass the full ARN as parameter.

Comment: `ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter` uses SSM  dynamic references under the hood (check the synthesized clouformation template)